# JS Plotly: Heatmap colours distorted in print

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

This happens only in print and not in a browser.

This is the browser view:
[image]

But in print pdf, it shows up like this:
[image]

code is same and even the print preview has the correct values:
[image]

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you are doing anything wrong. Heatmap cells are just pixels here, and the resulting image is upscaled with the browser applying the `image-rendering: pixelated;` rule (when `zmooth` is false) to prevent smoothing colors, and that rule seems to be lost during the html to pdf process. That said, I tried with a simple html page having just one heatmap and it works fine, at least from Chrome and Firefox. What happens if you print a simplified html page having just the heatmap ? The browser is involved in the process so you might want to try with different browsers.